# How I will get RSS and Atom blog feeds in my websites?

Tags: xml, rss, feed, atom-feed

My client wants to get RSS and Atom blog feeds in his website like blew.

Example RSS feed URLs:

1. http://www.omnivoracious.com/atom.xml
2. http://www.aldenteblog.com/rss.xml
3. http://www.chordstrike.com/index.rdf

SO, now how can I get RSS FEED link?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CMS like **WordPress**

**Update:**
As you said in the comments that you are already using WP,
WP has an inbuilt feed feature...
Just use this format -
https://www.yourwebsite.com/feed/

Comment: Yes, I am using WP

Comment: @SazidHasanMilon WP has built in feature for RSS, for e.g. https://www.yoursite.com/feed/